# Cython compilation include his own target

Tags: python, c++, cython, clang++

I'm having troubles with an odd error. I use Cython to compile some c++ files. It works perfectly fine under OS X but under Linux i have the following error.

```
clang++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/test.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ocv.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/fructueux.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Face_keypoint_extractor_minimal.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tools/mimic.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Unrestricted_local_binary_pattern_modified.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Over_sampling.o -L -o /home/AM/Documents/code_dw/Python_deep_dev/Cython_interface/First_import/test.so -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -ltbb -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem ./libFD.a

 => -L -o /home/AM/Documents/code_dw/Python_deep_dev/Cython_interface/First_import/test.so

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/home/AM/Documents/code_dw/Python_deep_dev/Cython_interface/First_import/test.so'
```

The -o is perfectly normal but i don't know the effect of the -L just before and i guess it is the reason it crashes.

Does someone has an idea of the reason why distutils and/or clang could produce such an output ?

PS : I have never written the string "test.so" in any of my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid but it always happens

in the setup.py :

```
library_dirs=[""]
```

Create the -L in the compiler command and the -L ignore the -o and get the next path.